# How can I remove older kernel in linux-generic-lts-raring series without installing a new one in the same series?

Tags: ubuntu, ubuntu-12.04, apt-get, apt

I have an vps running ubuntu 12.04 with kernel 3.8.0-34 in `linux-generic-lts-raring` series.

In this kernel series, there is a newest version 3.8.0-35.

Since I already installed an `linux-generic-lts-saucy` 3.11.0-15 kernel, I decide to remove the old raring kernel with:

```
$ sudo apt-get -s purge linux-headers-3.8.0-34 linux-headers-3.8.0-34-generic linux-image-3.8.0-34-generic
```

and the output:

```
Reading package lists...
Building dependency tree...
Reading state information...
The following extra packages will be installed:
  linux-headers-3.8.0-35 linux-headers-3.8.0-35-generic
  linux-headers-generic-lts-raring linux-image-3.8.0-35-generic
  linux-image-generic-lts-raring
Suggested packages:
  fdutils linux-lts-raring-doc-3.8.0 linux-lts-raring-source-3.8.0
  linux-lts-raring-tools
The following packages will be REMOVED:
  linux-headers-3.8.0-34* linux-headers-3.8.0-34-generic*
  linux-image-3.8.0-34-generic*
The following NEW packages will be installed:
  linux-headers-3.8.0-35 linux-headers-3.8.0-35-generic
  linux-image-3.8.0-35-generic
The following packages will be upgraded:
  linux-headers-generic-lts-raring linux-image-generic-lts-raring
2 upgraded, 3 newly installed, 3 to remove and 21 not upgraded.
```

The problem is that kernel 3.8.0-35 will be installed... and `linux-headers-generic-lts-raring` and `linux-image-generic-lts-raring` will be upgraded.

What I want is to completely remove:

- `linux-generic-lts-raring`
- `linux-headers-generic-lts-raring`
- `linux-headers-3.8.0-34`
- `linux-headers-3.8.0-34-generic`
- `linux-image-generic-lts-raring`
- `linux-image-3.8.0-34-generic`
- and other packages installed which provide packages above like `linux` `linux-server` `linux-image` `linux-headers-server` ... which I don't know yet.

I tried passing options like `--no-install-recommends` or `--no-upgrade` to purge command but no one worked.

Anyone can provide a command or an option that I can reuse in a chef cookbook reliably?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: http://askubuntu.com/questions/2793/how-do-i-remove-or-hide-old-kernel-versions-to-clean-up-the-boot-menu

Answer (score 0):

Ha! I manage to remove all these package without installing additional kernel 3.8.0-35 by adding "*":

```
$ sudo apt-get -s purge linux-headers-3.8.0-* linux-image-3.8.0-*

Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
Note, selecting 'linux-headers-3.8.0-33-generic' for regex 'linux-headers-3.8.0-*'
Note, selecting 'linux-headers-3.8.0-21' for regex 'linux-headers-3.8.0-*'
Note, selecting 'linux-headers-3.8.0-22' for regex 'linux-headers-3.8.0-*'
Note, selecting 'linux-headers-3.8.0-23' for regex 'linux-headers-3.8.0-*'
Note, selecting 'linux-headers-3.8.0-19' for regex 'linux-headers-3.8.0-*'
Note, selecting 'linux-headers-3.8.0-30' for regex 'linux-headers-3.8.0-*'
Note, selecting 'linux-headers-3.8.0-25' for regex 'linux-headers-3.8.0-*'
Note, selecting 'linux-headers-3.8.0-31' for regex 'linux-headers-3.8.0-*'
Note, selecting 'linux-headers-3.8.0-26' for regex 'linux-headers-3.8.0-*'
Note, selecting 'linux-headers-3.8.0-32' for regex 'linux-headers-3.8.0-*'
Note, selecting 'linux-headers-3.8.0-27' for regex 'linux-headers-3.8.0-*'
Note, selecting 'linux-headers-3.8.0-33' for regex 'linux-headers-3.8.0-*'
Note, selecting 'linux-headers-3.8.0-34' for regex 'linux-headers-3.8.0-*'
Note, selecting 'linux-headers-3.8.0-29' for regex 'linux-headers-3.8.0-*'
Note, selecting 'linux-headers-3.8.0-35' for regex 'linux-headers-3.8.0-*'
Note, selecting 'linux-headers-3.8.0-23-generic' for regex 'linux-headers-3.8.0-*'
Note, selecting 'linux-headers-3.8.0-31-generic' for regex 'linux-headers-3.8.0-*'
Note, selecting 'linux-headers-3.8.0-26-generic' for regex 'linux-headers-3.8.0-*'
Note, selecting 'linux-headers-3.8.0-34-generic' for regex 'linux-headers-3.8.0-*'
Note, selecting 'linux-headers-3.8.0-29-generic' for regex 'linux-headers-3.8.0-*'
Note, selecting 'linux-headers-3.8.0-21-generic' for regex 'linux-headers-3.8.0-*'
Note, selecting 'linux-headers-3.8.0-19-generic' for regex 'linux-headers-3.8.0-*'
Note, selecting 'linux-headers-3.8.0-32-generic' for regex 'linux-headers-3.8.0-*'
Note, selecting 'linux-headers-3.8.0-27-generic' for regex 'linux-headers-3.8.0-*'
Note, selecting 'linux-headers-3.8.0-35-generic' for regex 'linux-headers-3.8.0-*'
Note, selecting 'linux-headers-3.8.0-22-generic' for regex 'linux-headers-3.8.0-*'
Note, selecting 'linux-headers-3.8.0-30-generic' for regex 'linux-headers-3.8.0-*'
Note, selecting 'linux-headers-3.8.0-25-generic' for regex 'linux-headers-3.8.0-*'
Note, selecting 'linux-image-3.8.0-23-generic' for regex 'linux-image-3.8.0-*'
Note, selecting 'linux-image-3.8.0-31-generic' for regex 'linux-image-3.8.0-*'
Note, selecting 'linux-image-3.8.0-26-generic' for regex 'linux-image-3.8.0-*'
Note, selecting 'linux-image-3.8.0-34-generic' for regex 'linux-image-3.8.0-*'
Note, selecting 'linux-image-3.8.0-29-generic' for regex 'linux-image-3.8.0-*'
Note, selecting 'linux-image-3.8.0-21-generic' for regex 'linux-image-3.8.0-*'
Note, selecting 'linux-image-3.8.0-19-generic' for regex 'linux-image-3.8.0-*'
Note, selecting 'linux-image-3.8.0-32-generic' for regex 'linux-image-3.8.0-*'
Note, selecting 'linux-image-3.8.0-27-generic' for regex 'linux-image-3.8.0-*'
Note, selecting 'linux-image-3.8.0-35-generic' for regex 'linux-image-3.8.0-*'
Note, selecting 'linux-image-3.8.0-22-generic' for regex 'linux-image-3.8.0-*'
Note, selecting 'linux-image-3.8.0-30-generic' for regex 'linux-image-3.8.0-*'
Note, selecting 'linux-image-3.8.0-25-generic' for regex 'linux-image-3.8.0-*'
Note, selecting 'linux-image-3.8.0-33-generic' for regex 'linux-image-3.8.0-*'
Package linux-headers-3.8.0-19 is not installed, so not removed
Package linux-headers-3.8.0-19-generic is not installed, so not removed
Package linux-headers-3.8.0-21 is not installed, so not removed
Package linux-headers-3.8.0-21-generic is not installed, so not removed
Package linux-headers-3.8.0-22 is not installed, so not removed
Package linux-headers-3.8.0-22-generic is not installed, so not removed
Package linux-headers-3.8.0-23 is not installed, so not removed
Package linux-headers-3.8.0-23-generic is not installed, so not removed
Package linux-headers-3.8.0-25 is not installed, so not removed
Package linux-headers-3.8.0-25-generic is not installed, so not removed
Package linux-headers-3.8.0-26 is not installed, so not removed
Package linux-headers-3.8.0-26-generic is not installed, so not removed
Package linux-headers-3.8.0-27 is not installed, so not removed
Package linux-headers-3.8.0-27-generic is not installed, so not removed
Package linux-headers-3.8.0-29 is not installed, so not removed
Package linux-headers-3.8.0-29-generic is not installed, so not removed
Package linux-headers-3.8.0-30 is not installed, so not removed
Package linux-headers-3.8.0-30-generic is not installed, so not removed
Package linux-headers-3.8.0-31 is not installed, so not removed
Package linux-headers-3.8.0-31-generic is not installed, so not removed
Package linux-headers-3.8.0-32 is not installed, so not removed
Package linux-headers-3.8.0-32-generic is not installed, so not removed
Package linux-headers-3.8.0-33 is not installed, so not removed
Package linux-headers-3.8.0-33-generic is not installed, so not removed
Package linux-headers-3.8.0-35 is not installed, so not removed
Package linux-headers-3.8.0-35-generic is not installed, so not removed
Package linux-image-3.8.0-19-generic is not installed, so not removed
Package linux-image-3.8.0-21-generic is not installed, so not removed
Package linux-image-3.8.0-22-generic is not installed, so not removed
Package linux-image-3.8.0-23-generic is not installed, so not removed
Package linux-image-3.8.0-25-generic is not installed, so not removed
Package linux-image-3.8.0-26-generic is not installed, so not removed
Package linux-image-3.8.0-27-generic is not installed, so not removed
Package linux-image-3.8.0-29-generic is not installed, so not removed
Package linux-image-3.8.0-30-generic is not installed, so not removed
Package linux-image-3.8.0-31-generic is not installed, so not removed
Package linux-image-3.8.0-32-generic is not installed, so not removed
Package linux-image-3.8.0-33-generic is not installed, so not removed
Package linux-image-3.8.0-35-generic is not installed, so not removed
The following packages will be REMOVED:
  linux-generic-lts-raring* linux-headers-3.8.0-34* linux-headers-3.8.0-34-generic* linux-headers-generic-lts-raring*
  linux-image-3.8.0-34-generic* linux-image-generic-lts-raring*
0 upgraded, 0 newly installed, 6 to remove and 0 not upgraded.
Purg linux-generic-lts-raring [3.8.0.35.35]
Purg linux-headers-generic-lts-raring [3.8.0.34.34]
Purg linux-headers-3.8.0-34-generic [3.8.0-34.49~precise1]
Purg linux-headers-3.8.0-34 [3.8.0-34.49~precise1]
Purg linux-image-generic-lts-raring [3.8.0.34.34]
Purg linux-image-3.8.0-34-generic [3.8.0-34.49~precise1]
```

Answer (score 0):

***One-liner to remove old kernels versions***

**dpkg --list | grep linux-image | awk '{ print $2 }' | sort -V | sed -n '/'`uname -r`'/q;p' | xargs sudo apt-get -y purge**